# How to quickly convert groups in a pandas df to a list of separate arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas

I made this function which converts the groups within a pandas dataframe into a separate list of arrays:

```
def convertPandaGroupstoArrays(df):


    # convert each group to arrays in a list.
    groups = df['grouping_var'].unique()
    mySeries = []
    namesofmyseries = []

    for group in groups:
        #print(group)

        single_ts = df[df['grouping_var'] == group]

        ts_name = single_ts['grouping_var'].unique()
        ts_name = ts_name[0]
        namesofmyseries.append(ts_name)

        single_ts = single_ts[['time_series', 'value']]
        #set the time columns as index
        single_ts.set_index('time_series', inplace=True)

        single_ts.sort_index(inplace=True)
        mySeries.append(single_ts)

    return mySeries, namesofmyseries
```

However, my dataframe contains 80 million rows (many groups each containing 400 rows). I've been running the function all morning on just 5 million rows and it never seems to be ending. Is there a faster way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: Can you add sample data in the question? and what does the expected output look like?

Comment: While this code appears to leave room for optimization, imho you should consider to switch to a database (PostgreSQL, SQL Server, ...) for this amount of data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `groupby`:

```
def convertPandaGroupstoArrays(df):
    df1 = df.set_index('time_series')[['value']]
    return list(zip(*df1.groupby(df['grouping_var'])))[::-1]
```

Performance for 1M rows:

```
# Your version
244 ms ± 15 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

# Groupby version
62.3 ms ± 487 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```